# How to get Apple Watch UDID without Xcode?

Tags: apple-watch, udid

I want to get my teams Apple Watch UDIDs for register devices in provisioning portal.
but, my team members don't have Xcode.(not engineer)

Comment: "UniqueDeviceID" is a protected MobileGestalt key, so only Apple-signed apps (Xcode, iTunes, ...) can read that info programmatically from the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for now, there are no ways to get the watch UDID other than using Xcode.
Other ways, like configuration, or programmatically are not possible either.

Answer (score -7):

**Edit: The SEID is not the UDID**, and although you can register devices with it in the developer portal, it does not seem to work.

1. Start the Apple Watch App on your iPhone
2. Select the "My Watch" tab
3. Select "General"
4. Select "About"
5. Select "SEID" (at the very bottom)
6. Tap long on the cell until the context menu appears; select "Copy" and paste the number to wherever you want